# SQLAlchemy database migration error with db.relationships

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I keep getting the following error when trying to "flask db init" or "flask run" while using db.relationship:

```
TypeError: relationship() got an unexpected keyword argument 'query_class'
```

If I comment out the db.relationship line it works fine.

I'm trying to achieve this by using part of their documentation code below:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecretkey'

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///'+os.path.join(basedir,'data.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
Migrate(app,db)

class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    addresses = db.relationship('Address', backref='person', lazy=True)

class Address(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'),
        nullable=False)
```

**Environment:**
- Flask 1.1.2
- Flask-Migrate 2.5.3
- Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.4.3
- SQLAlchemy 1.3.17
- PyCharm 2020.1.1
- Windows 7

Comment: This code works for me with the latest versions of everything. What version of Flask, Flask-SQLAlchemy, SQLAlchemy are you on?

Comment: They all seem to be on the latest version. Flask 1.1.2, Flask-Migrate 2.5.3, SQLAlchemy 1.3.17, Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.4.3 + PyCharm 2020.1.1, Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by uninstalling Flask, Flask-Migrate and SQLAlchemy then reinstalling them.

```
#Uninstall
pip uninstall Flask
pip uninstall Flask-Migrate
pip uninstall SQLAlchemy

#Install
pip install Flask
pip install Flask-Migrate
pip install SQLAlchemy
```